# botan-2.4.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed

Tags: yocto, bitbake

i try to implement botan library in yocto, i have the recipe with following content

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://license.txt;md5=bf361fc63df3fa25652ee82c43b7601a"

SRC_URI = "https://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/botan/botan_${PV}.orig.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e52c6e15c0017eb2d61838f56f051ded"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "2d5696c75b89e3c2e888867907764ab063daca9a1a42ea35649792dace4eff83"

S = "${WORKDIR}/${BPN}-2.4.0"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build"

#DEPENDS = "pkgconfig"
inherit autotools pkgconfig

do_install () {
install -d ${D}${libdir}
install -d ${D}${libdir}/.debug/
install -d ${D}${includedir}/botan
install -m 0755 ${B}/libbotan-2.so ${D}${libdir}
install -m 0755 ${B}/libbotan-2.a  ${D}${libdir}
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/botan-2.4.0/src/botan/*.hpp ${D}${includedir}/botan
        rm ${WORKDIR}/botan-2.4.0/src/botan/*.cpp
        rm ${WORKDIR}/botan-2.4.0/src/botan/*.hpp
}

FILES_${PN} += " \
        ${libdir}/libbotan-2.so \
"
FILES_${PN}-dev += " \
        ${includedir}/botan/*.hpp \
"
FILES_${PN}-staticdev += " \
        ${libdir}//libbotan-2.a \
"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += " \
        ${libdir}/.debug/* \
"
```

When i try bitbake botan, i encountered error:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4
| make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile
```

Anything i doing it wrong or misinterpret?
i create this recipe using  recipetool create https://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/botan/botan_2.4.0.orig.tar.gz
I tried bitbake -c botan and bitbake again, it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells it could not find `Makefile` in source directory. From the `readme.rst` file present in `botan-2.4.0.tar.gz` it is said that to `run ./configure.py` before start compiling, which will generate `Makefile`. so try to add something like below to your recipe

```
    do_configure_prepend() {
        ${PYTHON} ${S}/configure.py
    }
```

Comment: /run.do_configure.6733: python: not found than i try with pytho3n instead getting error ERROR: botan-2.4.0-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/home/kj/BBB_yocto/poky/BeagleBone_minimal/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/botan/2.4.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.6847' failed with exit code 2:
python3: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
Any advice? thanks

Comment: what is your recipe name? try to set source dir like `S = "${WORKDIR}/Botan-${PV}"` and also check for file configure.py in source directory(${S}) after do_patch

Comment: HI Praveen, appreciate your input. my recipe is   botan_2.4.0.bb, i rework according your  suggestion., may i know how to check configure.py in bb receipt? Do you have any reference?Happy to check it out. After the rework  having the error , my bitake seem navigate to /usr/bin/python3 to check for configure.py.

Comment: | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| /usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.

Comment: is it legit for me to generate the Makefile first, than copy manually to the recipe directory?

Comment: No generating Makefile manually is not good idea. i will check your recipe

Comment: Can you try the modified solution above? Sorry that I missed adding `${S}´ to the configure.py

Comment: HI , i have attached the paste bin of my recipe https://pastebin.com/aDtvqGQE. I also attached tree of my recipe https://pastebin.com/Hn8EuCCS. Sorry for the trouble, this really is a whole new thing for me

Comment: Now above issue you posted resolved, just mark it as answer. new issue is it seems by default it generates Makefile for x86_64. For which machine you are building?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217124/discussion-between-praveen-muthusamy-and-kj-lau).